# caculate how many data Apache.HttpClient recevied?

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I simply want to measure the network speed server-client on HTTP.

For that, My Server API return the big data(1GB, byte array) and Client request to this API but will disconnect forcingly after specific seconds.

And then I will calculate how many client got and divide seconds.

I am using `CloseableHttpAsyncClient`, `HttpAsyncRequestProducer`, `AsyncCharConsumer<HttpResponse>`. and I summarize received data in `AsyncCharConsumer<HttpResponse>.onCharReceived()` and try to disconnect using `HttpGet.abort()`.

When I didn't disconnect forcely, summarized mount is correct but this request was aborted, summarized value is `0`. How can I get that? thanks.

[Apache HttpComponent Async Request Document Example](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/quickstart.html)